# Fowards/backwards compatibility of C/C++ code compiled with different NDKs?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, compatibility

I'm starting my first piece of Android programming, porting some libraries written in C and C++ to Android. I am not building an app, except for testing the libraries: the product is the libraries, which will be supplied to my customers. The libraries are mathematical modelling, running on the device, and have no web or cloud interfaces: customers who want to run them in the cloud already do that, using the Linux or Windows builds.

My initial customer is using NDK 14b. I could use that, or I could use the latest NDK, 16b. If I compile C code with NDK 16b, a compatible instruction set and the same C++ run-time and target API version as my customer, will they be able to use static libraries that I've built in their NDK 14b app?

The other way around is also interesting: if I use NDK 14b, and another customer comes along who uses NDK 16b, will static libraries I've built with 14b work in their 16b-built app? I'd be targeting an equal or earlier API to them, and the same instruction set and C++ run-time.

Addendum, much later: Building .so libraries turned out to be *so* easy that I've never used anything else.

Comment: There is _[a discussion here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329948/handle-backward-compatibility-on-api-changes)_ that deals with the general problem of backward compatibility

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be relevant. It's talking about web APIs, as far as I can see, and I'm talking about C/C++ code calling the Android OS APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You kindof cannot target the same C++ runtime when you use a different NDK release. The STL versions do not change too much, but there is no contract of their stability.

Except from this remark, static lib from NDK r16 will cooperate correctly with r14 and *vice versa*, but the bigger the gap is, the more glitches you should expect to handle.

In general, NDK improvements involve bug fixing, so there is an incentive to use the latest release. But major progress is done in support of newer platform versions. This means that if your library will be linked into an app that targets Lollipop, the advantages of r16 will be less prominent.

Note that if you can ship your library as a linked shared library (**so**), your interdependency with the host app will be significantly less, and in my experience this improves stability and reduces clashes. If that is relevant, this way is also more secure.

Comment: The one thing I'd add is that you do need to be conscious of the effect that your NDK API level (`APP_PLATFORM`, `ANDROID_PLATFORM`, or `minSdkVersion`, depending on your build system) has. That is (with a few small corner cases) the *minimum* API level that your code will work on. If you target 21, your clients' apps will not work on anything pre-L if they use your library.

Comment: Oh, and something Alex alluded to but didn't directly state: if you use the STL, your clients must use the same STL (as before, aside from a few small corner cases).

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the STL issue. I'm expecting to use libc++, which I'm used to on macOS. On that OS, libc++ seems to be thoroughly compatible backwards and forwards, if you use Apple's -mmacosx-version-min compiler option correctly. I guess I was thinking of the Android API version as being analogous. I do understand that if I set that for API 21 ("Lollipop"), my code won't run on anything older, but that is not a problem: this code is for fairly specialised apps.

Comment: I'll do .so shared libraries if I can, being used to them on Linux, but it's a piece of the learning curve that comes after being able to build the libraries, and their test harness, link them all into an Android app and run tests.

Comment: Well, **libc++** support is currently under development by the NDK team. The changes are minor, but if you are not lucky, you will step on a mine. Note that this library depends heavily on the **clang** compiler, which is a work in progress, too.

Comment: I don't think that building a static library is easier than shared. The Android architecture *requires* an **so** file in the end, to be deployed with an Android app. So, even if you want to ship a static library, you must build a shared library from it if you want to test it on a device in the context of an ANdroid app.